# Does the Extremely Clever Disguise discard your Training cards?

Tags: ninja-burger

In Ninja Burger, you can pick up various forms of training (such as *Training Course: Combat*), which give you a permanent +1 bonus to a skill (and can be used as an auto-success if played in response to failing a roll). They have one last line of text: **If your current character is lost, discard this card.**

How does this work with the card *Extremely Clever Disguise*, which lets you discard your character and pick a new one? (Because you've just been *disguised* as your old character until now.) You're not exactly "losing" your ninja, but you do discard the old character card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discard **Training Course: Combat**, because the rules text on the card specify, "If your current character is lost, discard this card." It did not specify how you lost it, only that you did. If it had said, "If your current character is lost, because you have no honor, discard this card." you would have a different answer. In general, I would play cards as written.

> **You Have No Honor!** -If your Honor is zero at the end of a round, you must apologize to your ancestors. This requires you to go to visit them, and unfortunately it will not be possible for you to come back. Discard all your cards and money. Now draw a new Ninja card and three Fortune cards . . . and see if your new character does better than your last one! You start with 6 Honor.